# How to set a sequential integer step in AmCharts' value axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I want to set a sequential integer step, i.e. `0,1,2,3,4,.......`, in [my charts](http://jsfiddle.net/zarm8pen/) `valueAxis`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the documentation, [`step`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#step) is a read-only value, so you can't set it yourself to influence the value axis step.  You have a couple of options to force your own step increment:

1) Set the valueAxis' [`autoGridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#autoGridCount) to false and then set [`gridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#gridCount) a large enough value for your minimum/maximum to get the desired step. A value of 20 works in your chart's case. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zarm8pen/2/)

2) Disable the labels and use [guides](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide) to draw each tick on the valueAxis. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vp1251yu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also set `minVerticalGap` and `minHorizontalGap` to 1.

here's the result http://jsfiddle.net/zarm8pen/19/

even though, it doesn't work properly when i set to 20 to get the step 0, 20, 40, 80, etc. sometime i get 0, 10, 20, etc sometime it's correct, i guess it still depend on the data itself.

but it works in your case.